# Allow writing of virtual CD/DVD in Virtual PC or Virtual Box to make it Virtual CD-RW/DVD-RW

Tags: virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc

May I know how to allow writing of data into a Virtual CD/DVD in Virtual PC or Virtual Box? Currently, if we mount a ISO file as a Virtual CD/DVD, we can only read it, and it cannot "behave" like a Virtual CD-RW or Virtual DVD-RW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to make a ISO file as a virtual CD-RW or Virtual DVD-RW.